# Display notification when a page is not seen

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

How can I display notification **"a new reply to your question"**   using ajax,php,mysql?
I am getting trouble even starting how to code.
As soon as somebody replies,I will have to check if the user has seen the page or not.
And display notification until the user has seen the page.

How can I start doing this, please give me a hint atleast.

Ok, I made a table that will contain the notification.
In this table the questionid,replyid,and the userid of person who asked the question is stored.

But I again ran into same problem. How will I know that the user who had asked question **HAS NOT SEEN THE ANSWER PAGE?**
Like stackoverflow, this site keeps on notifying me until and unless I see the answer page...how they do it? I searched in google many times like 'reply notification' or 'new answer notification '  etc etc but everybody is interested in displaying signin welcome notification or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://whathaveyoutried.com/.

Comment: You can make a new column in the reply table named "new" and create a function that retrieve the data from it. After that you make an ajax that calls the function every 10 second or every 1 second and return the function output.

Comment: @Netra I did add a row in new table..but what to do next?See my edited question above....

Comment: @netuser because when the user visits the page you update the row of the user from "new" to "old".

Comment: Thankyou @Netra.. I successfully made the notification.

Comment: I can accept your answer if you remove it from comment and post it as answer.....if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set cookie function onLoad event of the page, and when the user replies try to test if cookie exists and after the response you clean this cookie

Comment: How can cookie help me...like I am in new york and you in london(suppose) answer to my question, then how will cookie on your side notify me "a new answer" on my side?

Comment: Cookies are used on the same pc, but in your case you can set new colone in your data base, you can use the ip adress of user and many variables associated with the user